# messageBack escaping ampersand in displayText

Tags: json, botframework, microsoft-teams

After sending the following payload to `MSTeamsBot`:

```
{  
    "type":"messageBack",
    "title":"Sotto Mare Oysteria & Seafood Rating: 4.5",
    "displayText":"You chose Sotto Mare Oysteria & Seafood Rating: 4.5",
    "text":"sotto-mare-oysteria-and-seafood-san-francisco",
    "value":{  
             "property":"sotto-mare-oysteria-and-seafood-san-francisco"
    }
}
```

The `displayText` is changed from

> You chose Sotto Mare Oysteria & Seafood Rating: 4.5

to

> Sotto Mare Oysteria &amp; Seafood Rating: 4.5

Note that the `&` is being converted to `&amp;`

How can I get the text to include the ampersand symbol instead of its escape sequence?

Comment: Did you try `\&` or `&&`?

Comment: I found the same problem and seems I can't find a solution to solve this issue, what I can suggest as workaround is to avoid using this '&' for the `displayText` for now.

Comment: I have also found that double quotes are also escaped, as `&quot;` and could be a rendering limitation.  I'm still investigating that part though.  A similar issue was found at [this issue post (which has no comments)](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/32663047-im-back-buttons-should-not-escape-html-special-cha)

Comment: Another question:  How are you submitting your payload to the MSTeamsBot?  Is this a button press?  A textbox on a card?  Something else?

Comment: I am submitting it as textbox on a Card .

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this on the iOS version of Microsoft Teams, and the button I used to deliver the displayText payload did *not* escape the special characters, including the `&`.  The Windows desktop and web versions of Microsoft Teams, however, *did.*

This appears to be a per-platform environmental implementation for Microsoft Teams clients, with some escaping the ampersand, and others not.

Also, it seems the payload, from what I'm determining, does not have the escaped ampersand when the card was transmitted from bot to client (when I examined and decoded the card/button makeup, in my test implementation via the web browser version in Teams).

This has less to do with the Bot Framework itself, and more to do with the client being used to serve the Teams bot chat (be it Windows, in-browser, iOS, etc).  I would recommend reaching out to [MS Teams Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/teams) regarding this.